# how can I use regexp:sh_to_awk and regexp:match in erlang v5.10.4

Tags: erlang

I have a module using `regexp:sh_to_awk` and `regexp:match`.

But when I compile it, the  compiler warns me that the `regexp` module was removed from R15 and recommends me to use the `re` module instead.

I searched the erlang documentation but I can't find how to replace the two functions.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `regexp` module has been deprecated for a while and has now been removed, replaced by the [re](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) module.

The old **regexp:match** function has been replaced by the `re:run`  functions, which add a lot of functionality, such as returning captured parts as lists or binary (The old way of returning start position and length also remains):

```
> re:run("Test String","[a-zA-Z]{4}",[{capture,all,list},global]).
{match,[["Test"],["Stri"]]}
```

Read through the `re:run/3` documentation, it's worth it, just as all the other functions of the `re` module (like `compile` and `replace`).

The **regexp:sh_to_awk** has been removed. You can use the `filelib:wildcard`  functions for matching filenames, if that was your intended use of the old `regexp:sh_to_awk/1`  function.